# How to get an accurate method of time passed using audioSettings.dspTime?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

Thanks for looking and for any help / advice you might have.

I'm trying to sync audio with gameplay.

Is this an accurate method of finding out how much time has passed using audioSettings.dspTime?

I take a float representing time and multiply by song.clip.frequency.

```
    float myChosenAmountOfTimeInSamples = myChosenAmountOfTime * song.clip.frequency; 
    float audioSecondsLater = Audio + myChosenAmountOfTimeInSamples;
```

And this onto audioSettings.dspTime * song.clip.frequency

```
    float Audio = (float)AudioSettings.dspTime * song.clip.frequency;
    float audioSecondsLater = Audio + myChosenAmountOfTimeInSamples;
```

I'm using this code to see if it works. As far as I can tell it happens 1 second later

In Update

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)){
            StartCoroutine(test ());
        }
```

And the coroutine

```
IEnumerator test ()
{
    float Audio = (float)AudioSettings.dspTime * song.clip.frequency;
    float myChosenAmountOfTime = 1f;
    float myChosenAmountOfTimeInSamples = myChosenAmountOfTime * song.clip.frequency; 
    float audioSecondsLater = Audio + myChosenAmountOfTimeInSamples;

print ("Audio seconds later: " + audioSecondsLater);

while (true)
    {

        Audio = (float)AudioSettings.dspTime * song.clip.frequency;
        if (Audio >= audioSecondsLater)
        {
            print ("Audio Now: " + Audio); // Theoretically this is 1 second later
            break;
        }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1 / 1000f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you're on the right track. I've done sync before against a single AudioClip, but I keep all my timing in samples. To check the current sample I examine [AudioSource.timeSamples](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-timeSamples.html) on the clip that is playing. I use [REAPER](http://www.reaper.fm/) to examine the audio file and figure out at which sample in the file the events happen, and compare that to timeSamples to see if my sync event has happened yet.

AudioSource also has a [time](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-time.html) property which is the playback position in seconds, though see note in the documentation about inaccuracy when used with compressed audio.

Comment: Thanks for the input Eliot. I think my question might be quite ambiguous.

Comment: @Jim Feel free to edit the question to explain what you're trying to do more clearly.